How to send NMEA 2000 command with SignalK or Raspberry Pi
I have a Raspberry Pi running Open Plotter and Signal K connected to my NMEA 2000 network. I also have an Autonnic Wind Instrument that is connected. However, I had to install this off-centre, so I need to reset the unit's heading to account for this.
According to the instructions, I can reset the heading to 0 with the following:
Input PGNs
Custom (PGN: 127257). A 6-byte block of which only the first is used as follows:
Set Wind Heading to Zero = 7

Does anyone know how to do this using a Pi, SignalK or any other method?

Did you try using the 'cansend' command to write this information directly to the CAN bus? You would need to encode the data appropriately for the request.
